# Installing Ubuntu, but not getting a install menu

Tags: installation, 13.10

I was hoping I can get some help. I installed Ubuntu VIA usb. But when I was installing I never got the "Menu" To run along side or delete windows and run Ubuntu only. I don't want windows on this laptop. I want to be running 13.10 Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: may i know your Laptop specs and what is your USB Drive ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an option to decide the partitioning strategy, "Allocate Drive Space", which will offer options like "Install alongside windows", "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu", and "Something Else".

You should of course select "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu".

Comment: That's it I never get this menu. It's weird. I have it installed now, but I have it installed along with 8.1 and I just want Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using some OEM ISO which has certain boot options hardcoded into the image so that the installer assumes a certain partitioning strategy? Or is it just the normal ISO? What is the name / link of the image that you are using to install?